# visual studio 2008 installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I cleared windows temp file and %temp% from my system . (i installed vs 2008) but now i can't able to create new project (window application), whether VS 2008 installation file is related to temp. The error showing that doc settings/temp/ .... some file missing........

Answer (score 2):

not quite sure if you are actually missing the project templates or if the project templates themselves are failing, but if it's the former, then try

Open cmd.exe, goto \Common7\IDE.
Run "devenv /installvstemplates"

Also see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116(VS.80).aspx

HTH
Alex